# Why utf8::all and HTML::Table together produce weird warning?

Tags: perl

I wrote little wrapper subroutine to produce HTML-tables with [`HTML::Table`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aTable), same time i use [`utf8::all`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?utf8%3a%3aall) and together they produce a weird warning:

```
utf8 "\xE4" does not map to Unicode at /usr/share/perl5/HTML/Table.pm line 756.
```

Line 756 is deeply middle of POD, so i can't figure out, what may be wrong there.

Example script to reproduce the problem:

```
use 5.012;
use utf8::all;
use HTML::Table;

my @head = qw(col1 col2 col3);
my @table = (
        [ qw( yks kaks kolm) ],
        [ qw( neli viis kuus) ],
    );

say table_draw( table => \@table, header => \@head );

sub table_draw {
    my (%args) = @_;

    $args{border} ||= 0;
    $args{padding} ||= 1;
    $args{width} ||= '95%';

    my $table = new HTML::Table(
                -head=> $args{header},
                -data=> $args{table},
                -width=> $args{width},
                -border=> $args{border},
                -padding=> $args{padding},
            );

    return $table;
}
```

EDIT: changed min Perl version, because under 5.10 i did not get warning either,

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: @daxim: i tried under 5.10.1 and did not get warning but i do under 5.12 and 5.14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line number's not quite right, but the error seems to be with the following gentleman/lady's name in the POD:

Ville Skyttä, ville.skytta@iki.fi

Not actually utf8, I suspect. Presumably a small bug-report is in order.

Comment: Thank you! Btw, Ville is Finnish male name.

Comment: I wanted to report the bug, but discovered, that i already reported it more than year ago. With solution ;)